# Jquery element creation on the fly

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I am processing a JSON file and want to display the contents in a `<div>`
i dont know the number of records of the json file so i want to create teh appropriate divs on the fly. how should i go about it?

the structure i am looking at is: 
`<div class=1>
  <div class=2>
   <div class=3>
  </div></div></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var div = $('<div/>')` will create an empty `div`, in which you can insert your data, and ultimately insert it into the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.each` to loop through your JSON data as seen in **[this example from the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)**